# How to make spring boot configuration module independent of spring boot version?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to develop my `springboot` configuration module.

For example, I want to the behaviors of serialization and `deserializion` consistent in the Spring `ConverterSPI` and `JsonHttpMessageConverter/XmlHttpMessageConverter.`

So,i try to register all converters in Spring ConverterSPI to global configuration  `JsonHttpMessageConverter/XmlHttpMessageConverter` provides.
And decide whether to open by configuration.

For this spring-boot configuration module, I don't want to rely on the spring-boot version.

Otherwise, the actual spring-boot project needs to exclusion the transitive dependencies spring boot when introducing this module.

How to achieve this goal?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `provided` scope.

Comment: @chrylis It looks like i'm looking for,thanks.